# llvm-qemu executive binary

Tags: arm, llvm, qemu, cross-compiling

I'm a user of llvm-qemu project on http://code.google.com/p/llvm-qemu/, which is based on qemu-0.9.0. I want to let it run an arm application to observe the execution procedure.

I'm using ubuntu-i386 and cross compiler arm-linuxgnueabi-gcc for the cross compiling.

I wrote a hello.c source file:

```
int main(){
    return 0;
}
```

and use the compilation command line,

```
arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc -mcpu=arm926ej-s hello.c
```

and then I use

```
qemu-arm a.out
```

But it shows:

```
mmap:Operation not permitted.
```

How to solve the problem?
Thank you!